# How do allow a range of IPs in /etc/hosts.allow but deny a single IP within that range in /etc/hosts.deny?

Tags: ssh, security, hosts

My `/etc/hosts.allow` file contains:

```
sshd: 225.73. , 164.41.
```

My `/etc/hosts.deny` file contains:

```
sshd: 225.73.24.25 , 164.41.45.63
```

The problem I'm facing is that if I try to SSH from `225.73.24.25` or `164.41.45.63` the server is allowing me to SSH in.

The scenario I want is that all IPs in the range `225.73.`  or `164.41.` are allowed in except hosts with the IPs `225.73.24.25` or `164.41.45.63`.

I would be grateful if someone could help with this.

Comment: Because access rules in hosts.allow are applied first, they take precedence over rules specified in hosts.deny. https://web.mit.edu/rhel-doc/4/RH-DOCS/rhel-rg-en-4/s1-tcpwrappers-access.html Use firewall instead

Comment: Try except operator https://www.mankier.com/5/hosts_access#Operators or deny, allow order https://www.mankier.com/5/hosts_options#Access_Control

Comment: I was about to say calculate the subnets without one given IP, but EXCEPT appears to be a better way to excluding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EXCEPT operator in `hosts.allow` like this:

`sshd: 225.73. , 164.41. EXCEPT 225.73.24.25 , 164.41.45.63`

See man hosts.allow:

> EXCEPT Intended use is of the form: `list_1 EXCEPT list_2`; this
> construct matches anything that matches list_1 unless it matches
> list_2.

Answer (score -1):

225.73. or 164.41. are allowed in except hosts with the IPs 225.73.24.25 or 164.41.45.63.
all of this ips will still able to log in change filter
sshd: 225.73.24.25 - 164.41.45.63 , 192.168.1.1 , 192.168.100.1 - 192.168.100.255

Comment: Can you format this answer better?

Maybe provide an example, so it's really clear.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm voting this answer down as I think it might be misleading.